# Let $X,Y,Z$ be sets. If $X\Delta Z=Y$ then $Y\Delta X = Z$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove the following basic theorem:

> Let $X,Y,Z$ be sets. If $X\Delta Z=Y$ then $Y\Delta X = Z$.

I'm familiar with the Symmetric difference definition but every way I go I got stuck. What is the easiest way to prove this theorem?

Comment: $Y\Delta X=(X\Delta Z)\Delta X=...$

Answer (score 3):

Note that symmetric difference is commutative and associative i.e. $A\Delta B = B\Delta A$ and $(A\Delta B) \Delta C = A\Delta (B \Delta C)$ for all sets $A,B,C$. Also $A \Delta \emptyset = \emptyset \Delta A = A$ for all sets $A$.

Assume $X \Delta Z = Y$. Then from this assumption and by applying the mentioned properties of $\Delta$ we have

$$
Y \Delta X = (X \Delta Z) \Delta X = X \Delta (Z \Delta X) = X \Delta (X \Delta Z) = (X \Delta X) \Delta Z = \emptyset \Delta Z = Z.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the fact that the symmetric difference operation is defined uning X-OR , and that  ( A w B) ( with w meaning : exclusive OR) is equivalent to :

~ ( A <--> B)

as a truth table shows it easily.

I'll use X, Y and Z as sentence symbols meaning "x belongs to X", "...to Y", "...to Z" ( respectively).

Translated in the language of membership relation, the original statement is :

(X w Z) <--> Y , which is equivalent to :

(1) ~ [( X w Z) w Y ]

(2) ~ [ (Y w X ) w Z ]  ( By : commutativity and associativity of X-OR )

(3)  (Y w X ) <--> Z

But (3) is equivalent to what we wanted to arrive at.